# ECS exit with code 0, stopped and restarted docker container many times

Tags: docker, docker-compose, exit-code, amazon-ecs

I am deploying a docker with ECS. I can run the docker ok on local, but when i use ECS, it always stops it and then restart a new one. I checked the docker log, there is no error either. I also checked docker stats, things looks ok. Below is what the ecs log shows:

```
2018-02-16T07:24:01Z [INFO] Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:035804961478:task/c13ba3f3-6ac8-49c5-a649-3d90e363ce4d]: Cgroup resource set up for task complete
2018-02-16T07:24:01Z [INFO] Task engine [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:035804961478:task/c13ba3f3-6ac8-49c5-a649-3d90e363ce4d]: pulling container openimage-http concurrently
2018-02-16T07:24:01Z [INFO] Task engine [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:035804961478:task/c13ba3f3-6ac8-49c5-a649-3d90e363ce4d]: Recording timestamp for starting image pulltime: 2018-02-16 07:24:01.209507829 +0000 UTC m=+30.870498308
2018-02-16T07:27:29Z [INFO] Adding image name- 035804961478.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/adobesearch/openimage:classifierscpu to Image state- sha256:b0b930a705e7df39404de30c58da2e573a2deb519b212c0d0a7ab74cf9d85192
2018-02-16T07:27:29Z [INFO] Updating container reference openimage-http in Image State - sha256:b0b930a705e7df39404de30c58da2e573a2deb519b212c0d0a7ab74cf9d85192
2018-02-16T07:27:29Z [INFO] Saving state! module="statemanager"
2018-02-16T07:27:29Z [INFO] Saving state! module="statemanager"
2018-02-16T07:27:29Z [INFO] Task engine [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:035804961478:task/c13ba3f3-6ac8-49c5-a649-3d90e363ce4d]: Finished pulling container 035804961478.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/adobesearch/openimage:classifierscpu in 3m27.982214992s
2018-02-16T07:27:29Z [INFO] Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:035804961478:task/c13ba3f3-6ac8-49c5-a649-3d90e363ce4d]: Cgroup resource set up for task complete
2018-02-16T07:27:29Z [INFO] Task engine [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:035804961478:task/c13ba3f3-6ac8-49c5-a649-3d90e363ce4d]: creating container: openimage-http
2018-02-16T07:27:29Z [INFO] Task engine [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:035804961478:task/c13ba3f3-6ac8-49c5-a649-3d90e363ce4d]: created container name mapping for task: openimage-http -> ecs-classifierscpu-http-TaskDefinition-1AYVW69U0MPZX-1-openimage-http-b2cbd59b9dd7f4f7c501
2018-02-16T07:27:29Z [INFO] Saving state! module="statemanager"
2018-02-16T07:27:29Z [INFO] Task engine [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:035804961478:task/c13ba3f3-6ac8-49c5-a649-3d90e363ce4d]: created docker container for task: openimage-http -> e9710d91b36113d319dc04a274fe0fdf2908e102c25767ab2fab14e822277049
2018-02-16T07:27:29Z [INFO] Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:035804961478:task/c13ba3f3-6ac8-49c5-a649-3d90e363ce4d]: unable to create task state change event []: create task state change event api: status not recognized by ECS: CREATED
2018-02-16T07:27:29Z [INFO] Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:035804961478:task/c13ba3f3-6ac8-49c5-a649-3d90e363ce4d]: Cgroup resource set up for task complete
2018-02-16T07:27:29Z [INFO] Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:035804961478:task/c13ba3f3-6ac8-49c5-a649-3d90e363ce4d]: redundant container state change. openimage-http to CREATED, but already CREATED
2018-02-16T07:27:29Z [INFO] Task engine [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:035804961478:task/c13ba3f3-6ac8-49c5-a649-3d90e363ce4d]: starting container: openimage-http
2018-02-16T07:27:30Z [INFO] Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:035804961478:task/c13ba3f3-6ac8-49c5-a649-3d90e363ce4d]: sending container change event [openimage-http]: arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:035804961478:task/c13ba3f3-6ac8-49c5-a649-3d90e363ce4d openimage-http -> RUNNING, Ports [{5000 8080 0.0.0.0 0}], Known Sent: NONE
2018-02-16T07:27:30Z [INFO] Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:035804961478:task/c13ba3f3-6ac8-49c5-a649-3d90e363ce4d]: sent container change event [openimage-http]: arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:035804961478:task/c13ba3f3-6ac8-49c5-a649-3d90e363ce4d openimage-http -> RUNNING, Ports [{5000 8080 0.0.0.0 0}], Known Sent: NONE
2018-02-16T07:27:30Z [INFO] Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:035804961478:task/c13ba3f3-6ac8-49c5-a649-3d90e363ce4d]: sending task change event [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:035804961478:task/c13ba3f3-6ac8-49c5-a649-3d90e363ce4d -> RUNNING, Known Sent: NONE, PullStartedAt: 2018-02-16 07:24:01.209507829 +0000 UTC m=+30.870498308, PullStoppedAt: 2018-02-16 07:27:29.191733309 +0000 UTC m=+238.852723707, ExecutionStoppedAt: 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC]
2018-02-16T07:27:30Z [INFO] TaskHandler: batching container event: arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:035804961478:task/c13ba3f3-6ac8-49c5-a649-3d90e363ce4d openimage-http -> RUNNING, Ports [{5000 8080 0.0.0.0 0}], Known Sent: NONE
2018-02-16T07:27:30Z [INFO] TaskHandler: Adding event: TaskChange: [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:035804961478:task/c13ba3f3-6ac8-49c5-a649-3d90e363ce4d -> RUNNING, Known Sent: NONE, PullStartedAt: 2018-02-16 07:24:01.209507829 +0000 UTC m=+30.870498308, PullStoppedAt: 2018-02-16 07:27:29.191733309 +0000 UTC m=+238.852723707, ExecutionStoppedAt: 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC, arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:035804961478:task/c13ba3f3-6ac8-49c5-a649-3d90e363ce4d openimage-http -> RUNNING, Ports [{5000 8080 0.0.0.0 0}], Known Sent: NONE] sent: false
2018-02-16T07:27:30Z [INFO] TaskHandler: Sending task change: TaskChange: [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:035804961478:task/c13ba3f3-6ac8-49c5-a649-3d90e363ce4d -> RUNNING, Known Sent: NONE, PullStartedAt: 2018-02-16 07:24:01.209507829 +0000 UTC m=+30.870498308, PullStoppedAt: 2018-02-16 07:27:29.191733309 +0000 UTC m=+238.852723707, ExecutionStoppedAt: 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC, arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:035804961478:task/c13ba3f3-6ac8-49c5-a649-3d90e363ce4d openimage-http -> RUNNING, Ports [{5000 8080 0.0.0.0 0}], Known Sent: NONE] sent: false
2018-02-16T07:27:30Z [INFO] Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:035804961478:task/c13ba3f3-6ac8-49c5-a649-3d90e363ce4d]: sent task change event [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:035804961478:task/c13ba3f3-6ac8-49c5-a649-3d90e363ce4d -> RUNNING, Known Sent: NONE, PullStartedAt: 2018-02-16 07:24:01.209507829 +0000 UTC m=+30.870498308, PullStoppedAt: 2018-02-16 07:27:29.191733309 +0000 UTC m=+238.852723707, ExecutionStoppedAt: 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC]
2018-02-16T07:27:30Z [INFO] Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:035804961478:task/c13ba3f3-6ac8-49c5-a649-3d90e363ce4d]: redundant container state change. openimage-http to RUNNING, but already RUNNING
2018-02-16T07:27:30Z [WARN] Error publishing metrics: stats engine: no task metrics to report
```

I also deployed another simple docker test image on ecs, i ONLY changed the tag name (the tag of the other docker image in ECS) in the template, and it works perfectly. But the previous failed case, the docker works perfectly well on local as well in instance if i manually do docker run. I really don't know where else to look for the error.

Comment: Are you using ECS services as part of your cluster that could be taking down your tasks due to health checks or something related? What's the output of `docker logs <your-container>`?

Comment: docker logs are ok, not any error. Yes i am using ECS as part of cluster. The container just already stops when running ok, then ECS restarts another one

Comment: Are there any logs in the ECS Service event history?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't tell anything meaningful. I further find out that it is more of the docker image i built, which ECS always fail. So I am wondering if ECS does not work well with any particular docker images with some libraries installed? (like tensorflow, mkl, etc.)

Comment: @ayy did to get it worked?